# Implementing ALU

Tags: verilog, alu

I'm trying to implement an ALU given specific function codes.

For some reason, the code below doesn't run and has errors according to the compiler.

> Error (suppressible): alu.v(61): (vlog-2388) 'result' already declared in this scope (alu).
>   Error (suppressible): alu.v(67): (vlog-2388) 'operand0' already declared in this scope (alu).
>   Error (suppressible): alu.v(67): (vlog-2388) 'operand1' already declared in this scope (alu).
>   Error (suppressible):alu.v(68): (vlog-2388) 'control' already declared in this scope (alu).
>   Error: (vlog-13069) alu.v(71): near "<=": syntax error, unexpected <=.
>   Error: alu.v(71): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'result'. Is there a missing '::'?

If I remove the declarations of result, operand0, operand1, and control as wire and regs I still get errors saying that "result" is out of scope or inaccessible. I'm really confused with this part and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I feel the problem is somewhere with regs and wires but I'm not sure.

```
module alu 
(
//--------------------------
// Input Ports
//--------------------------
input   [31:0]  operand0, 
input   [31:0]  operand1, 
input   [3:0]   control,
//--------------------------
// Output Ports
//--------------------------
output  [31:0]  result,
output          zero,
output          overflow
);



// Signal Declarations: local params




// Signal Declarations: reg





// Signal Declarations: wire


always @(*)
begin
case(control) 
4'b0000: result= operand0 | operand1; // OR 

4'b0001: begin
        result= operand0 & operand1; // AND
     end  
default: result = 4'b0;
endcase
end


endmodule
```

I changed the code above to the modified version. I still get errors though:

Now it says:
(vlog-2110) Illegal reference to net "result". 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with your code. There two ways of declaring inputs and outputs:

```
  module alu (
         input   [31:0]  operand0, 
         input   [31:0]  operand1, 
         input   [3:0]   control,

         output reg [31:0]  result,
         output          zero,
         output          overflow
             );
```

and second method is :

```
   module (operand0,operand1,control,result,zero,overflow);
   input [31:0]  operand0; 
   input   [31:0]  operand1;
   input   [3:0]   control;
   output reg [31:0]  result;
   output          zero;
   output          overflow;
```

I hope you can see the difference. Hence, in your code you are re-declaring the inputs and outputs.

Also non-blocking assignments i.e. **<=** are usually used for sequential logic. For combinational logic blocking assignment is preferred i.e. **=**.

And if you want to define your output as **reg**, it has to be used inside **always** block otherwise define it as wire.

Your code can written as follows:

```
module alu 
(
input   [31:0]  operand0, 
input   [31:0]  operand1, 
input   [3:0]   control,

output reg [31:0]  result,
output          zero,
output          overflow
);


always @(*)
begin
 case(control) 
  4'b0000: result= operand0 | operand1; // OR 

  4'b0001: begin
           result= operand0 & operand1; // AND
           end  
 default : result =4'b0;
endcase
end
 endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your explanation was very clear! Now, I get the error "Illegal reference to net "result" 3 times. Can I not equate variables to result within the case? I edited the statement in the question above. I made the changes you mentioned as well.

Comment: There was a typo in the default case. I used **<=** by mistake instead of **=** . I have corrected now.

Comment: You cannot equate the variables to result within the case as whenever the inputs operand0 and operand1 change, output changes. Hence they must be added to the sensitivity list. So always @(*) means all the inputs are included in the sensitivity list which is going to effect the output.